# Patch 7405 v1.1

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

I add the patch 7405 v1 and after I add v1.1 I have this errors

```
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1642 (offset 162 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 242.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 507 (offset 136 lines).
checking file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 185.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
```

I don't know why I get an error on that Abstract file ...
I change the files from a Magento 1.9.2.1 blank and still, I have this error

Comment: check where any old patches are installed correctly?

Comment: Yes and i check if someone change the core file that's why i add the file from a fresh magento

Comment: did you update from core file from same version 1.9.2.1? compare with core file space or any changes in core file

Comment: I check the file it's the same from the version 1.9.2.1

Comment: I check the patch and i have the same code for the line 192 and when i reverte the patch i get fail on this line

Comment: i should  change the patch code ?

Comment: I fix this issue

Comment: I am sorry, i am bit busy on my work. if you are resolved please share answer it will hwlp for others